# Visual Studio 2017 and TFS see what files are checked out and to who

Tags: tfs, version-control, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2015 I could use the TFS Power Tools and then do a "Find by Status" to get a list of all checked out files and who has them checked out.

Does anyone know of a way to do this in Visual Studio 2017? I've read that they do not plan on releasing a TFS Power Tools 2017.

Thank you,

Comment: Register your vote to have this added back in: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365649/restore-missing-tfs-power-tools-functionality-in-v.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, the "Find by Status" feature only works for Server workspace. If you're using Local workspace, it doesn't show anything.

[image]

As a workaround, maybe you could use the [tf status](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/status-command) command instead, it displays information about pending changes to files and folders.

Or you could use TFS API, here is an example: http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/07/16/tfs-2010-sdk-get-list-of-user-workspaces-and-checked.aspx.

Comment: Find by status was working perfectly fine for me in VS 2015. It just isn't there in VS 2017. Your post has forced me to look more into the tf status command and I've got it working.

If anyone else is interested if you open the Developer Command Prompt and then navigate to the projects folder this command will give you a list of all checked out items and who has it checked out:

tf status .\* /recursive /user:*

Comment: With the VS 2017 Enterprise command prompt, In order for the `tf status .* /recursive /user:*` command to work I had to change `.*` to `*` so that it's `tf status * /recursive /user:*` - otherwise it would just say "There are no pending changes." when in fact there were some.