# TFS Online - What have I got checked out

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I (or rather we) use TFS online for source control ([mycomapny].visualstudio.com with a single "collection" with multiple projects

Being recently thrust into the administration role (rather than just a contributor, using Visual Studio integration), Is there any way, using the web portal to find out who has what checked out throughout the entire collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t find the pending changes (checked out) in web portal. You can retrieve pending changes through [TF command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/status-command), but you cannot view pending changes in a remote local workspace.

There is a similar issue: [Visual Studio 2017 and TFS see what files are checked out and to who](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41882659/visual-studio-2017-and-tfs-see-what-files-are-checked-out-and-to-who)